# How is "if one does not differ" translated using the word 異なる and the ば-ending?

Tags: grammar, verbs, conditionals

異なる is the dictionary form.
To express the idea of condition, one has to change the u into an e and add the suffix ba.

異なれば = If one differs.

How do you express the idea of a negative condition -> if one does not differ?

Answer (score 3):

"if one does not 'verb'" can be expressed as : verb + ない form + ば form = verb + なければ

It is similar to the ば form conditional for い adjectives:
高い(い adj) + ば form = 高ければ

In your particular example : 異ならなければ